# How to access one document at a time in a mongodb collection using nodejs? I have the collection as shown below

Tags: node.js, mongodb

"_id" : "dashboardurls",
    "urls" : [
        {
            "name" : "google",
            "link" : "http://www.google.com"
        },

and a set of similar documents.
        ]
I want to extract only "http://www.google.com" using a query. I used db.collection.findOne({'urls.name' : 'google'}); but I got the whole collection back instead of only www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you use Mongoose. In that case, use the [`.select()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) method to extract the `link` field alone.

Comment: I did not get you, I have a set of urls apart from google, I have facebook, twitter etc. How can i loop in through all these urls and print one at a time? Do i need to instal moongoose?